# Polymer, Deepstream.IO and RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, polymer-1.0, amqp, deepstream.io

we'd like to set up a notification engine that uses AMQP. To achieve this, we're using RabbitMQ. That's fine, the server is installed and configured.

Now, we'd like to access the RabbitMQ message queues from a browser, so we need to have a wrapper around AMQP. For this, we found deepstream.io. This is especially fine, because we use Polymer as frontend which is supported by deepstream.io.

We configured deepstream.io to use rabbitMQ as backend, but the connection from Polymer to deepstream.io does not work:

The  sets up the connection, we can see this in the deepstream server log (INCOMING_CONNECTION), but the  component seems to be the problem. After a long timeout the log file reports a CONNECTION_AUTHENTICATION_TIMEOUT.

How can I set the user name and passwort specified in the deepstream.io config file in the  component?

Thank you!

Comment: To improve the question, I think it would be helpful to see the log from the server you mention as well as the configuration file (if any). What evidence do you have that it is an authentication problem? More details would be helpful.

Comment: Just wondering: Are you using a ds-login element? (https://deepstream.io/tutorials/integrations/frontend-polymer/#connectivity)

Answer (score 0):

According to the `ds-tutorial-polymer` repo you connect to deepstream as follows:

```
        <ds-connection 
            url="localhost:6020" 
            ds={{ds}}>
        </ds-connection>

        <template is="dom-if" if="[[ds]]">

            <ds-login 
                auto-login
                ds="[[ds]]">
            </ds-login>

            <todos-list 
                name="polymer_example/todos"
                ds="[[ds]]">
            </todos-list>

        </template>
```

This exposes deepstream as a global `ds` for you to pass to other records and lists.

If you switch off `auto-login` within the ds-login you will need to call the login method on the prototype. An example ( and rest of documentation ) can been seen here:

http://deepstreamio.github.io/deepstream.io-tools-polymer/components/deepstream.io-tools-polymer/#ds-login

Comment: Thank you, @yasserf! I have already seen this but I did not achieve to connect. I am still relatively new to web frontend development and did not achieve to pass username and password to the <ds-login>-connection.